# Number of records returned after using prepared statement

Tags: php, prepared-statement

I am currently taking an IT course in which people can bring in their computer(s) and the class works on them to get experience.  Right now, the instructor has the customers fill out a sheet of paper giving their name, phone number and the computer's issue(s).  However, he would like to use a PHP page to allow the students or himself look back to see what this person's previous issues were (if any).  I am using PDO and prepared statements to query the database, but I am having trouble figuring out how to get the number of records returned by the prepared statement. I've tried using stmt_num_rows, but it doesn't appear to be working.  Here is the code I have so far:

```
$custID = $_GET["id"];
$compID = $_GET["compID"];

$stmtIssues = $db->prepare("SELECT IssueID, DateRequested, Issue, ActionsTaken FROM ISSUES WHERE ComputerID=:compID AND CustomerID=:custID ORDER BY DateRequested");
$stmtIssues->bindParam(":custID", $custID);
$stmtIssues->bindParam(":compID", $compID);

$stmtIssues->execute();
$numIssues = stmt_num_rows($stmtIssues);
```

Am I doing this right?

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Chris

Comment: I think you will find your answer here: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php

Comment: OK, I've changed the code to the following:

Comment: $numIssues = $stmtIssues->rowCount();     But now I am getting -1 for the value instead of 2 which is what I should be getting.  I'm not sure but based on the link, rowcount is used after a DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE query, not a SELECT query.

Comment: You should take a look at example 2: `Example #2 Counting rows returned by a SELECT statement`

Answer (score 0):

You could do a few things:

Solution one, if you just want the count, let the database count for you:

```
$stmtIssues = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(IssueID) FROM ISSUES WHERE ComputerID=:compID AND CustomerID=:custID ORDER BY DateRequested");
$stmtIssues->bindParam(":custID", $custID);
$stmtIssues->bindParam(":compID", $compID);
$stmtIssues->execute();
$numIssues = $stmtIssues->fetchColumn();
```

Solution two, if you're going to display the results in addition to the count:

```
$stmtIssues = $db->prepare("SELECT IssueID, DateRequested, Issue, ActionsTaken FROM ISSUES WHERE ComputerID=:compID AND CustomerID=:custID ORDER BY DateRequested");
$stmtIssues->bindParam(":custID", $custID);
$stmtIssues->bindParam(":compID", $compID);

$stmtIssues->execute();
$rows = $db->fetchAll();
$numIssues = count($rows);

foreach ($rows as $row) {
  echo $row['IssueID']; // you can add other columns and/or formatting here too.
}
```

Solution one is quicker and returns only the count. Solution two, on the other hand, returns all details you may want to display.